# Re-direct pre-filled link

Tags: javascript, redirect, google-apps-script, google-forms, google-apps-script-editor

I sent out an email with the incorrect url link for people to fill out a form

I want to be able to re-direct

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1idgfcX7LYUssTzwnR2MnNDWnXXIkMY0u6xrvBVv0oQ4/prefill?

to

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSe2glzQIwXycngR0DF6oi6gzUCK_X3IVHdVhnS3tzoj2fkIQg/viewform?usp=sf_link

Tried google script editor

function myFunction() {location.replace("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSe2glzQIwXycngR0DF6oi6gzUCK_X3IVHdVhnS3tzoj2fkIQg/viewform?usp=sf_link")
}

Get "ReferenceError: "location" is not defined. (line 1, file "Code") ERROR

I want to re-direct

Comment: Don't think it's possible

Comment: This is not possible at all unfortunately